# Obtaining a list of all image formats that an Android device supports

Tags: android, image, media, file-format

The [Android Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) page mentions:

> Note that any given mobile device may provide support for additional formats or file types not listed in the table.

Is there a way to obtain a complete list of all image formats that an Android device supports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's highly unlikely that device manufacturers would bother to support additional image formats so I wouldn't suggest spending much time looking into this further honestly. Also don't forget that even if one vendor supports a non-standard format, another probably won't.

If they did and they support compression of that format you could call [Bitmap.CompressFormat.values()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.CompressFormat.html#values%28%29) to get a list assuming they followed the Android pattern and you don't have an Android SDK released by the manufacturer to look at.

Comment: Note that Google's CTS requirements probably means that developers aren't even allowed to add extra entries to the CompressFormat class.